# python split a vector format string

Tags: python, string

I have a string input in the following format: (x,y) where x and y are doubles.

For example : (1,2.556) can be a vector.

I want the easiest way to split it into the x,y values, 1 and 2.556 in this case.

What would you suggest?

Comment: `x = (1,2.556)`, `print x[0]` `print x[1]`

Comment: its not good, i get "(1"  and "2.556)"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use code like this:

```
import ast
text = '(1,2.556)'
vector = ast.literal_eval(text)
print(vector)
```

The `literal_eval` function does not have a security risks associated with `eval` and works just as well in this particular case.

Comment: I give this a definite up-vote. I'll keep my answer involving `eval` since all Python programmers need to be aware of that function, but a safe version of eval for something like this is definitely preferable.

Answer (score 1):

`eval` works:

```
>>> s = "(1.2,3.40)"
>>> eval(s)
(1.2, 3.4)
>>> x,y = eval(s)
>>> x
1.2
>>> y
3.4
```

`eval` has potential security risks, but if you trust that you are dealing with strings of that form then this is adequate.

Comment: If the tuple contains integers, they will be interpreted as integers.

Comment: @Kupiakos True -- but the OP *did* say "in this case 1 and 2.556" and not "1.0". In most cases ints change to floats as needed, the important thing is that they can be used in numerical computations.

Answer (score 1):

The eval answers are good.  But if you are sure of the format of your strings -- always start and end with parentheses, no spaces in the string, etc., then you can do this fairly efficiently:

```
x, y = (float(num) for num in s[1:-1].split(','))
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the first and last `(`, `)` and then do splitting according to the comma.

```
re.sub(r'^\(|\)$', '',string).split(',')
```

**OR**

```
>>> s = "(1,2.556)"
>>> x = [i for i in re.split(r'[,()]', s) if i]
>>> x[0]
'1'
>>> x[1]
'2.556'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure they'll be passed in exactly this way, try this:

```
>>> s = '(1,2.556)'
>>> [float(i) for i in s[1:-1].split(',')]
[1.0, 2.556]
```